# Why did Moshe Rabbeinu need to stretch out his hand?

Tags: commentaries, moshe-rabbeinu, plagues-makkos, bo

[At the start of the plague of darkness](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.10.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), G-d tells Moshe Rabbeinu to stretch out his hand towards Heaven, that there may be darkness of the land of Mitzrayim:

> And the L-rd said to Moshe, Stretch out thy hand towards heaven, that there may be darkness over the land of Miżrayim, darkness which may be felt.

I saw that most of the mefarshim discuss the concept of חֹֽשֶׁךְ (darkness). However, I was not able to find explanations on why Moshe Rabbeinu needed to stretch out his hand, specifically towards Heaven.

Are there any mefarshim that discusses this idea? Please share any "pearls" on this subject.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53448/why-cant-moshes-hands-perform-miracles

Comment: Are you asking why the heavens would be the source of darkness?

Comment: Especially why Moshe needed to lift his hands and yes, why the heavens would be the source of darkness.

Comment: Moshe lifted his hands for other makos that originated from the heavens, like ברד. Maybe here it symbolizes the blocking of sunlight?

Comment: It seems to me that God told Moshe Rabeinu to stretch out his hand when performing the makos because in this way it was clear to the Mitzrim that Moshe (and ultimately, God) was the force behind the makah and that it wasn't just coincidence.

Comment: Joshua Berman in Ani Maamin generally suggests that "mighty hand" and "outstretched arm" are terms only used in the Exodus. It is appropriated from Egyptian royal propaganda and is frequently used.

Comment: @ezra That makes sense. Any commentators that discuss this same idea?

Comment: Are you asking, What was Moshe's role in the makkos? If so, it's a good general question; some of the makkos make it clear that Moshe (or Aharon) and their staffs were given the job and the power to make the makkah happen.

Comment: @MichoelR yes and no. I am asking why particulair, Moshe needed to stretch out his hand towards heaven. For example, in Shemos 9:8-9, we see that Moshe throw a  handful of soot from the kiln towards the sky. This is similair to what I am asking for. Why was there a need for Moshe to perform an action, and afterwards, G-d "covered the earth with darkness" and why especially with hand gestures? Why not praying?

Comment: @Shmuel As I said, he did it (or directed Aharon to do it) on every one of the plagues. The Midrash says that all the plagues (דצ"ח etc.) were inscribed on the staff, which was the tool used. I am assuming that Hashem empowered it. - In your case, do you think Moshe had the staff in his hand? See Exodus 17:9,11.

Comment: @Shmuel See also Exodus 8:1, "and *bring up* the frogs...". Command form. They were told to *do* it.

Comment: @Shmuel And Exodus 9:22,23: "Raise up your hand... And Moshe pointed the staff..."

Comment: @MichoelR then yes, I think Moshe had the staff in his hand (Ibn Ezra says he used it to pray).

Comment: @Andrew that seems to be a wonderful chiddush (insight). If you could back this up with sources, if it were up to me, you could write this up as an answer.

Comment: which episode??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sforno explains (in parshas Chukas, when Moses is ordered to speak to the rock "and it shall give its waters") that most Biblical miracles *bend* the laws of nature, and thus require some physical action to get them started.

The only one that successfully suspended the laws of nature entirely was Joshua stopping the sun, which used speech instead (just as God used speech to create the world).

When Moses was ordered to hit the rock at the beginning of his time in the desert, that was a "typical" miracle -- a physical action bent the laws of nature, and a spring appeared nearby.

At the end of the time in the desert, he was supposed to *transform* the rock itself into water -- a suspension of laws of nature -- and was ordered to use speech to do so. For whatever reason he didn't do that, and instead hit the rock as before, producing a "garden-variety" miracle instead.

Comment: Where is this Sforno located?

Comment: @Shmuel in Chukas.

Comment: Great answer. I am inclined to check it. However, there are a few points that are still not clear, including the fact that Moshe only stretched out his hands towards heaven. He did not do anything physical as far as I can tell, right?

Answer (score 2):

The Rabbinu Bahya address this [question here](https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Shemot.10.21.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> All miracles are essentially manifestations of a power above or beyond
> the natural forces operating in the universe...
> The letters in the word
> ויהי are the ones that depict matter coming into existence and that is
> why Moses with the help of his staff was able to work this kind of
> miracle.

It would seem from this that it was Moshe’s doing which caused the plagues to come. If you look at this page (only sources): https://alhatorah.org/The_Plagues_%E2%80%93_Natural_or_Supernatural/2 there is a large debate about what caused the miracles and plagues to come.

Comment: TY for bringin this Rabbeinu Bahya. Really interesting. See this answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28957/27180   -does this also apply in this case? If so, are there sources that discuss this?

Comment: I would argue that yes it is the same. I think it should be posed as a new question along the lines of how miraclous are mircales. The Alhatorah link i sent has most of this argument there

Comment: That page you've linked is empty unfortunately...

Comment: https://docdro.id/jntBaW2 
I made it into a document, it all in hebrew, hope thats ok

Answer (score 1):

Great question Shmuel!

I think Moshe lifting up his hands resembled bringing down this darkness on Bnei Yisrael, and this darkness was that of Gehinnom (Shemot Rabah 14:2) which is located above, as the Midrash Hanelam says, גיהנם למעלה, דכתיב ואת נפש אויביך יקלענה בתוך כף הקלע. This also fits in well with the Rabbeinu Bachaye that miracles are a manifestation of power from above. The Yismach Moshe (Bo 5:1) based off the אהבת דודים דף מ"ג ע"ב, says that if this darkness wouldn't have came Bnei Yisrael wouldn't have been redeemed because in Shemot Rabah 14:3 that it was dafka darkness that needed to come to kill all the sinners of Bnei Yisrael so that the Egyptians would not see Hashem killing the Jews. (Look at the Or HaChaim hakadosh on Shemot 10:22 for why dafka Moshe uses his hands and not his staff).

Comment: Wonderful explanation, especially that from the Yismach Moshe. I've read the Or HaChaim, and he says: "Inasmuch as the darkness was of a supernatural kind, Moses did not consider it appropriate to raise his staff against supernatural phenomena" - the only question that arises from this is that this wasn't the only "supernatural" plague right? So why do we see this especialy with this plague?

Comment: I had that question as well, but I'm not sure